# Apache CXF: how to return failure response from an interceptor

Tags: java, cxf

I have written a custom interceptor that does some parameter validation. I want to be able to return an error code and serialize a JAXB-annotated class as the response body.

If I throw a WebApplicationException, it doesn't have any special processing done to serialize the Response object inside (which makes sense; I assume that is done by another interceptor).

How should I go about stopping the interceptor chain but still have JAXB serialize the response entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least in the CXF JAX-RS interceptor flow, if you set:

```
message.getExchange().put(Response.class, response);
```

...then the actual service does not get invoked, while the other phases do get invoked. Haven't dug in to the CXF code to see where that logic kicks in.

So I built a response like this:

```
Response response = Response
    .status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
    .entity(new ErrorEntity("This is a JAXB object with an error string"))
    .build();
```

I also have some custom authentication running in a CXF JAX-RS filter and I only want to check the parameters when the authentication is alright, so I set my parameter interceptor class to run during the `PRE_INVOKE` phase.

Comment: But this way doesn't work if we work with SOAP protocol. Could someone please provide updates for the SOAP case?